# pip3 -V should print pip3 version but returns No module named 'pip' in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, pip, python-3.7

I am using Python 3.7.2 in Ubuntu 16.04. I installed the *python3-pip* package from the default Ubuntu repositories, and it is reported by apt that I have installed python3-pip 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4 (version 8.1.1), but pip3 does not work properly. `pip3 -V` should print the pip3 version, but it returns `No module named 'pip'` instead.

```
root@VM-0-8-ubuntu:/usr/bin# python -V
Python 3.7.2
root@VM-0-8-ubuntu:/usr/bin# pip3 -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
root@VM-0-8-ubuntu:/usr/bin# sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@VM-0-8-ubuntu:/usr/bin# pip3 -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
root@VM-0-8-ubuntu:/usr/bin# sudo apt updaate
E: Invalid operation updaate
root@VM-0-8-ubuntu:/usr/bin# sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://mirrors.tencentyun.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrors.tencentyun.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                 
Ign:3 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu trusty InRelease                              
Hit:4 http://mirrors.tencentyun.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease     
Hit:5 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu trusty-security InRelease        
Hit:6 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu trusty-updates InRelease                   
Hit:7 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu trusty-proposed InRelease                  
Hit:8 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu trusty-backports InRelease                 
Hit:9 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu trusty Release                             
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
root@VM-0-8-ubuntu:/usr/bin# sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@VM-0-8-ubuntu:/usr/bin# sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@VM-0-8-ubuntu:/usr/bin# pip3 -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
root@VM-0-8-ubuntu:/usr/bin#
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

It might be broken. You can try

```
sudo apt purge python3-pip  
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

If that doesn't work you might be using non packaged pip version and so it is possible the `pip` main as moved to `pip._internal`. In your pip3 file change `from pip import main` to `from pip._internal import main`. You can find pip3 file location by typing `which pip3` in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

pip is packaged separately from Python in Ubuntu (*python-pip* and *python3-pip*). Your version of pip3 (version 8.1.1) is not recognized by Python 3.7.2 which is not from the default Ubuntu 16.04 repositories. Therefore you must force a reinstall of pip3. Open the terminal and type:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py  
python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

Check the version of pip3 to make sure that it is the latest version.

```
$ pip3 -V
pip 19.0.2
```

The reason why Python 3 is unable to find pip3 is due to the sorry state of your software sources which you should fix immediately or else errors of this type will keep on reoccurring. You should never mix software sources from two different releases of Ubuntu, in your case xenial (16.04) and trusty (14.04). The easiest way to fix your software sources is to simply replace whatever you currently have in `/etc/apt/sources.list` with the default Ubuntu 16.04 software sources. A standard Ubuntu 16.04 sources.list looks like this:

A standard sources.list file for Ubuntu 16.04 looks like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` for editing in nano text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

An alternative way of doing it is to comment out all lines that contain the string `trusty` in `/etc/aptsources.list` by preceding each line that contains the string `trusty` with a `#` character.

The instructions for using nano are always displayed at the bottom of the page. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

After you have repaired sources.list, run `sudo apt update` to refresh the list of available packages. You can also switch the default mirror to a mirror that is closer to you in the *Ubuntu Software* tab of Software & Updates application. That way software installation and updates will download faster.